# Windows 10 with Azure Active Directory not giving option for Email Signin

Tags: domain, login, windows-10, entra-id

Like in the title, I've got a few Windows 10 machines. Upgraded from Home to Pro, added them to the Azure AD. There are anywhere from 1-3 local accounts on each. When I go to Start->User where I would expect to see

```
Change Account Settings
Lock
Sign out

--

Switch User
```

I'm not getting **Switch User** option at all, it's gone. So then I try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> and **Switch User** is there. Once I get the the Login Page. I'm missing the icon in the bottom left corner **"Other User"** and have no option to use the AD logins to sign into the machine.

Help!

Comment: The build number of **win10 Pro** is **1607** ? Please run winver.exe to check it .

Comment: Can't check until Monday, if it is, will I have to refresh the Operating System?

Comment: I just want to reproduce it in my lab . Before posting the comment above ,I added my win10 test computer into Azure AD ,but that issue didn't occur .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test *win10Pro is 1607* ( **new installation** ) , when I only add the Azure account into "***Connect to work or school***" , I still can't get the option "other user".

I need to follow the steps below additionally :

1. **the button "Connect" above the azure account** :

   [image]
2. **Within the pop up window , click "Join this device to Azure ActiveDirectory"** :

   [image]
3. **Sign in the Azure account again to join into azure AD** :

   [image]
4. **Last , you would get this**:

   [image]
5. **Try to log out and check if "other user" exists .**

Comment: The problem I was having was I was trying to do it through a non-admin account. As soon as I logged into the local admin account those options appeared. Before the "Join this device to Azure Active Directory" wasn't even showing on that popup.